# Есть ли аналог термина "продакт-плейсмент", но с учётом намеренного искажения названия бренда?

Tags: ономастика, терминология, неологизмы

Существует такое понятие, как продакт-плейсмент, когда в произведениях искусства упоминаются или демонстрируются продукты различных брендов (персонаж курит сигареты Camel, смотрит телевизор Sony и т. д.). А как назвать практику, когда названия/логотипы реальных фирм немного изменяются (Somy вместо Sony, логотип ананаса вместо яблока фирмы Apple), но в целом остаются узнаваемы? Известен ли вам такой термин или вы можете предложить собственный вариант?

"Грамота.ру" даёт такой ответ (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310897)).

> Предполагаем, что специалисты по ономастике уже нашли термин, обозначающий практику использования *коммерческих названий*, похожих на брендовые наименования. Поскольку нам этот термин пока не известен, то допускаем возможность употребления неологизмов, способных выразить идею ложного дублирования коммерческих имен; ср.: *коммерческая квазиноминация*, *квазинаименования*, *квазиназвания*.